# increasing "count" every time an object is created and added to an array

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I created a constructor with methods to create "student" objects and part of it is supposed to assign a student number to each student and increase that number by one with each student created.. mine aren't increasing.

this is the constructor

```
String firstNameInput;
public Student(String fName, String lName, String maj, double gpa)
{
    this.firstName = fName;
    this.lastName = lName;
    this.major = maj;
    this.gpa = gpa;
    sNumber = 1234567;

}
```

Here's the method that returns the student number

```
public int getsNumber() {

    return sNumber + count++;
}
```

here's my toString method

```
public String toString()
{
    return sNumber + " " + firstName + " " + lastName + " " + major + " " + gpa;
}
```

and here's where a student gets added.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Student s1 = new Student("Terra", "Ramey", "EE", 3.4);
    list.add(s1);
```

Let me know if I need to include all of my code to figure out where the problem is, but I think it's with one of these

Answer (score 2):

`count++` is located inside the method `getsNumber()`. There are two problems with that:

- The method is never called (at least, not in the code you've shown), hence you don't see the number increase.
- You would presumably call this method whenever you want to know the student number of a student - so *every time* you try to figure that out, the number *will* increase.

Since this looks like homework, I won't tell you where to place `count++`, but here's a strong hint: which method is run each time a new student is created (and never otherwise)?

Also, see the other posters' advice about `static` (you haven't shown the declaration of `count`, so we can't tell if you're already using it). However, please make sure that you understand what `static` does and how a static variable is different from a nonstatic one (a lot of new programmers end up throwing `static` around, thinking it's magic and hoping it will solve their problems).

Answer (score 0):

Add a static variable to the class. Something like the following :

```
private static int count = 0;
private int studentNumber;
```

Then in the constructor add the following :

```
public Student(String fName, String lName, String maj, double gpa)
{
  this.firstName = fName;
  this.lastName = lName;
  this.major = maj;
  this.gpa = gpa;
  sNumber = 1234567;
  count = count +1; // to keep the count
  this.getStudentNumber = count;
 }
```

Also add the following method to the Student class:

```
  public int getStudentNumber(){
     return this.studentNumber;
  }
```

Then in your main you can access the count by :

```
 Student student = new Student(//parameters);
 System.out.println(Student.count);
 System.out.println(student.getStudentNumber());
```

Comment: `getStudentNumber` is missing a `return` statement

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use static fields to store the current count, I think you'll find adding a `private static int currentCount` to the class and then assigning the field `sNumber = count++;` might work for you.

Comment: I shouldn't have given it away... Aasmund has the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use an AtomicInteger instead of just an int. That way, your constructor can be called by several threads simultaneously safely.